# Format painter Outlook on the web versus the desktop

Tags: microsoft-outlook, outlook-web-access

Shortcuts for format painter in Outlook include <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>V</kbd> as well as <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> but none of these work, from my experience, for Outlook web application.

Going into “Settings > View all Settings” > also does not offer an add format painter icon either.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There will be some differences between Outlook desktop client and Outlook for web.

Based on my test on Outlook for web, I found that we can use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> shortcut to enable format painter.

Please select the area and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, then the icon of the format brush is displayed. At this point you just need to use the mouse to swipe the format.